# No audio output after starting qtractor in Fedora 20

Tags: audio, fedora, pulse-audio, jackd

I have installed qtractor to start experimenting with music composition/production. However, after starting the application, the computer seems to redirect its audio output and the other applications are unable to output audio as they were before. (e.g.: Youtube video in Firefox)

I have looked for answers online but none seemed to solve my problem. Does anyone have experience with this kind of issues?

Also, When starting qtractor I get the following errors, which are probably related with this issue:

> Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/60)(1: Operation not permitted)
>
> AcquireSelfRealTime error
>
> Cannot lock down 42435354 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
>
> Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/55)(1: Operation not permitted)
>
> JackClient::AcquireSelfRealTime error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure jackd is not running , killing it restored my audio.